# ASP.Net MVC Postback from View to Controller shows null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I've a problem with ViewModel posting back to a controller, but the ViewModel not being mapped correctly from the View to the Controller.

**TopicId** and **Content** should contain values, however, when posted back, they do not:

**VS Debug:**
[image: ss]

**ViewModels:**

```
  public class PostViewModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfTopic { get; set; }
}

public class ReplyViewModel
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

}

public class PostListAndReplyVM
{
    public List<PostViewModel> PostViewModel { get; set; }
    public ReplyViewModel ReplyViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model centreforum.Models.PostListAndReplyVM

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Post</legend>

         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReplyViewModel.TopicId)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReplyViewModel.Content)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReplyViewModel.Content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReplyViewModel.Content)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

**Generated HTML:**

```
<form action="/Post/List/7/" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />    <fieldset>
    <legend>Post</legend>

         <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TopicId must be a number." data-val-required="The TopicId field is required." id="ReplyViewModel_TopicId" name="ReplyViewModel.TopicId" type="hidden" value="7" />

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="ReplyViewModel_Content">Content</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="ReplyViewModel_Content" name="ReplyViewModel.Content" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ReplyViewModel.Content" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

As you can see from the generated HTML, the TopicId definitely has a value: `value="7"`

Can anyone see where the problem is between the form post, and the controller, which is expecting the ReplyViewModel?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Can you show the HTTPGET Method of public ActionResult List()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input field names are prefixed with `ReplyViewModel` (because of the `model => model.ReplyViewModel.*` lambda), so you need to indicate this information to the model binder:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult List([Bind(Prefix = "ReplyViewModel")] ReplyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively have your List action take the PostListAndReplyVM model:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult List(PostListAndReplyVM model)
{
    // obviously only model.ReplyViewModel will be bound here because
    // those are the only input fields in your form
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a hack.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the fact that your view is typed to `PostListAndReplyVM` - so it creates names such as `ReplyViewModel.Content` - but, because your controller action expects a `ReplyViewModel`, these fields can't be bound (i.e. there is no such thing as `ReplyViewModel.ReplyViewModel.Content`).

Change your controller action:

```
public ActionResult List(PostListAndReplyVM reply)
```

Alternatively - if that's your whole view - just type it to `ReplyViewModel` instead (and update your HtmlHelper expressions accordingly).

Answer (score 2):

Its null because you bound it to another model

In view

@model centreforum.Models.PostListAndReplyVM

In Action ReplyViewModel

try to bind like

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(PostListAndReplyVM model)

    {
    }
```

Comment: Hi - PostListAndReplyVM contains two viewmodels (I've removed the HTML outside the form, for the PostViewModel) - in the form, I'm referencing this by: => model.ReplyViewModel.TopicId - thanks.